# Multiple regex patterns to find. Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, matcher

I need to calculate separately number of words and sentences in string and i have these two methods which works fine:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s|\\w+\\,|\\w+\\.|\\w+\\?|\\w+\\!*$");
    Matcher match1 = pattern.matcher(s);
    while(match1.find()) {
        counterWords++;
    }
```

and for sentences:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^?!.][?!.]");
    Matcher match2 = pattern.matcher(s);
    while(match2.find()) {
        counterSentences++;
    }
```

The next task is to calculate it again, but in one loop, so I tried:

```
while(match1.find() || match2.find()){
    if(match1.find()){
        counterWords++;
    }
    if(match2.find()){
        counterSentences++;
    }
```

However, the method is not working properly, it counts sentences correctly, but word counter is 2 times less that actual number of words. Most probably I don't understand completely how matcher.find() works, could somebody explain what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem with a single loop, you need your matcher to find either words or end-of-sentence markers, and then tell you which it found.  This can be done using "capturing groups".

```
    String s = "Hello, user.  How many words and sentences are there?  Count them!";

    int words = 0;
    int sentences = 0;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)|([.?!])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(1) != null)
            words++;
        else if (matcher.group(2) != null)
            sentences++;
    }

    System.out.printf("%d words and %d sentences%n", words, sentences);
```

> 11 words and 3 sentences

Regex explanation:

`(\w+)|([.?!])` - after translation of `\\` to `\`
`(___)________` - capture group #1.
`_\w+_________` - one or more word characters.
`_____|_______` - match the first part of the expression or the second.
`______(_____)` - capture group #2.
`_______[.?!]_` - sentence terminator character.

The first call to `matcher.find()` will match the `Hello`, recording it as capture group #1.  The next call skips over the comma and space and matches `user`, again recording it as capture group #1.  The third call matches the period (`.`) in the second part of the regular expression, recording it as capture group #2.  This continues until the exclamation mark (`!`) is matched.  The next call to `matcher.find()` returns false, since no more matches can be found.

The `if` statements check whether group #1 or group #2 captures were filled in, which determines whether a word or a sentence terminator was encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Each call to find() will search for the next match and in your combined while loop you are calling find() twice in each loop for match1 and match2, first in the while condition and then again in the if conditions, but you are only increasing the counter for the second find.

Also since you first call find() for words in the while condition find() for sentences will never be called since there are always equal or more words than sentences and the sentence counter will work correctly.